# breadth search first maze solver using queues

Tags: java, queue

I have to write a program that follows a breadth first search using queues to solve a maze. I think I almost have it done but when I run it, it says it does not contain a main type. Also can some one explain to me what is wrong with the code on line 47 and 48 (i = current.i and j=current.j) it should be fine but i get an error message that says it "cannot be resolved or is not in field, i though declaring above the while loop would be fine. It is also not critical but me teacher asked for us to use a repaint() method so we can see the maze solve itself. I'm not really sure how to use thus method but I have included that code as well. Any help to get this program running would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class MazeSolver {
public static final int WALL = 1, OPEN = 0, GOAL = 2, START = 3;
public static final int ACTIVE = 4, SOLUTION = 5;
    private int[][] maze = {
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    };

public static Point startSearch(int[][] grid) {
    int x = -1, y = -1;
    for (int col = 0; col < grid.length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            if (grid[col][row] == 3) {
                x = col;
                y = row;
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static Point[] algorithm(int[][] maze) {
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Point> path = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Point>();
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Point> predecessor = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Point>();

    Point start = startSearch(maze);
    Point current;
    Point north, south, east, west;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    path.offer(start);
    while (!path.isEmpty()) {
        current = path.poll();
        i = current.i;
        j = current.j;
        if (i == maze.length - 1 && j == maze.length - 1
                && maze[i][j] == '0') {
            Point[] trail = new Point[path.size()];
            while (path.isEmpty()) {
                for (int k = 0; k < path.size(); k++) {
                    trail[k] = path.poll();
                } return trail;
            }
        }

        east = new Point(i, j + 1);
        south = new Point(i + 1, j);
        west = new Point(i, j - 1);
        north = new Point(i - 1, j);
        if (j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1 < maze.length && maze[i][j + 1] == '0'
                && predecessor.contains(east) == false) {
            predecessor.offer(east);
            path.offer(current);
            path.offer(east);
        } else if (i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 < maze.length
                && maze[i + 1][j] == '0'
                && predecessor.contains(south) == false) {
            predecessor.offer(south);
            path.offer(current);
            path.offer(south);
        } else if (j - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 < maze.length
                && maze[i][j - 1] == '0'
                && predecessor.contains(west) == false) {
            predecessor.offer(west);
            path.offer(current);
            path.offer(west);
        } else if (i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 < maze.length
                && maze[i - 1][j] == '0'
                && predecessor.contains(north) == false) {
            predecessor.offer(north);
            path.offer(current);
            path.offer(north);
        }

    }

    return null;
}

public int[][] getMaze() {
    return maze;
}

public static void main(String args) {
    new MazeSolver();
}
```

and here is the method we are supposed to use for repaint(), this part isn't crucial but some help or an explanation of how it works would be great.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class MazeViewer extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final MazeSolver parent;
    public MazeViewer(MazeSolver parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        int[][] maze = parent.getMaze();
        int cellSize = Math.min(getWidth() / maze[0].length, getHeight()
                / maze.length);
        graphics.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        for (int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < maze[0].length; col++)
                drawCell(graphics, maze[row][col], row, col, cellSize);
    }
    private void drawCell(Graphics graphics, int mazeCellValue, int row,
            int col, int cellSize) {
        switch (mazeCellValue) {
        case MazeSolver.WALL:
            graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            break;
        case MazeSolver.OPEN:
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            break;
        case MazeSolver.GOAL:
            graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
            break;
        case MazeSolver.START:
            graphics.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        case MazeSolver.ACTIVE:
            graphics.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            break;
        case MazeSolver.SOLUTION:
            graphics.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        }
        graphics.fillRect(col * cellSize, row * cellSize, cellSize,
                cellSize);
        graphics.setColor(Color.GRAY); // border
        graphics.drawRect(col * cellSize, row * cellSize, cellSize,
                cellSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: A `java.awt.Point` has fields `x` and `y`, not `i` and `j`...

Comment: Just curious, why is this post downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your program cannot be run because you've declared your main function as this

```
public static void main(String args)
```

but it actually should have an array of Strings as the argument. ie. this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```